# How to create appointment with all in Outlook c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I have troubles with sending appointments to shared calendar programatically. I know that the standard way is as below:

```
MAPIFolder sharedFolder = mapiNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = sharedFolder.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
//Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = sharedFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment"); ///Second option
```

But probably it is equal to clicking into shared calendar and require write rights.

I need to do it as below in GUI, this allow to send appointment even if I do not have write rights:

NOTE: (In English) New appointment --> New appointment with all

[image]

NOTE2: If I send it by standard way (see code below), it will not send it to shared folder.

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
newAppointment.Start = startT;// DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
newAppointment.End = stopT;
newAppointment.Subject = name;
newAppointment.Location = loc;
newAppointment.Body = body;
newAppointment.AllDayEvent = false;
//newAppointment.Recipients.Add(application.Session.CurrentUser.Name);
for (int i = 0; i < rec.Count; i++) newAppointment.Recipients.Add(rec[i]);
Outlook.Recipients sentTo = newAppointment.Recipients;
sentTo.ResolveAll();
newAppointment.Save();
newAppointment.Display(true);
newAppointment.Send();
newAppointment.Close(OlInspectorClose.olSave);
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mailbox owner as an attendee and send it:

```
newAppointment.Recipients.Add(recipient);
newAppointment.Send();
```

Comment: This is not the problem. I posted only start of the code. This is the whole.

Comment: So do you see the meeting invitation in the Sent Items folder? Does the attendee receiving the invitation? Note that a tentative appointment in the Calendar folder will be created after the invitation is received when Outlook is running.

Comment: I can see it only in my calendar, if we are talking about second presented code. Same problem as here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf599e51-0e25-4f58-ad5a-e7a68c18a2b6/create-appointments-on-shared-calendar?forum=vsto

Comment: Once again, do you see the meeting invitation in the Sent Items folder? Does the attendee receiving the invitation?

Comment: Also, do not use **both** Display and Send - it is either/or.

Comment: Cannot see it in Sent item folder. But see it in my calendar. The appointment exists for me even if I am not present in recipients. If it is sent manually, it is in send folder.